# How do I check if a proton chain user exists properly and reliably from the front-end?

Tags: javascript, api, blockchain

If I go to https://protonscan.io/accounts/username
I get a 400 response for a user that doesn't exist and a 200 response for a user that exists on get_account (https://proton.greymass.com/v1/chain/get_account)

How do we check this properly and reliably and "Nice to have": How do we get the avatar for that user or other information, all from the front end?

Thanks.

Comment: Zachary Oakes from the proton Telegram group mentioned: https://proton.eosusa.news/v2/state/get_account?account=grat - and it works, but this is one provider, what happens if they go offline? How do I add redundancy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution I chose is this:

```
let userProvided; // here I get the username from the front-end
// then I fetch the user's data
fetch('https://proton.eosusa.news/v2/state/get_account?account=' + userProvided).then(response => {
  return response.json();
}).then(data => {
// after the data is parsed into an object we can use it here
   console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: The API used in the solution is not working anymore, I used this instead:
https://proton.pink.gg/v2/history/get_creator?account=

Answer (score 0):

I use that code on the backend (TypeScript).

```js
async isAccountExist(newAccountName: string): Promise<boolean> {
    const rpc = new ProtonRPC();
    const account = await rpc.getAccount(newAccountName);
    if (account) 
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Can be shorter by returning `!!account`

Comment: There is a gist here https://gist.github.com/SuperstrongBE/c3239e6c033de75cbfbefd4c7a3731fc#file-eosservices-ts-L7

Comment: That's very nice, but at the moment I am trying to solve it on the front-end so the server doesn't have to work for this bit.

Comment: This works from front end too 
But for pure rest API, you could use axios / fetch response code, or a good old try catch